# Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in "" on line 9

Tags: php, error-handling

Here is my php code:

```
<?php include("inc/incfiles/header.inc.php")?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Member Index</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome <?php echo ($_SESSION['SESS_fname']);?></h1>
<a href="member-profile.php">My Profile</a> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<p>This is a password protected area only accessible to members. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I know something I wrong with the code but I don't know how to fix it. My error says: "Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\Smasher\member-index.php on line 9"

How can I fix the error so it will say the user's first name? The first name in the database table on mySQL is called `fname`.

Comment: @mario. Same basic problem, but that one was specific to CakePHP and its session helper. (See the accepted answer to that question, which wouldn't help this user at all.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Add

```
session_start();
```

at the beginning of your page before any HTML

You will have something like :

```
<?php session_start();
include("inc/incfiles/header.inc.php")?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" conte...
```

Don't forget to remove the space you have before

Answer (score 8):

First, you'll need to add `session_start()` at the top of any page that you wish to use `SESSION` variables on.

Also, you should check to make sure the variable is set first before using it:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_fname'])){
    echo $_SESSION['SESS_fname'];
}
```

Or, simply:

```
echo (isset($_SESSION['SESS_fname']) ? $_SESSION['SESS_fname'] : "Visitor");
```

Comment: Not obvious for beginners coming here for tips.  Between tags like: `<?php session_start() ?>`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because of that "at the top of ***any page*** that you wish to use SESSION variables". If you are passing between a.php, b.php and c.php, you need to open the session at the top of all three. It is a common beginner mistake to only open it on the first page.

Comment: Also, don't forget to call `session_unset()` and `session_destroy()` at then of the last page ***and*** is any `catch (Exception $e)`, to tidy up